# Better practice to design cache system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm going to create a cluster for my project.

I'm confusing which strategy should I take it on my system.

There are many `Web App` servers and `database` servers.

The query takes several seconds to complete.

So I'd rather to use cache as more as possible.

The cluster is under auto scaling control on AWS.

So, should I put all the cache in `redis server` and get all Web app to access it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The is no silver bullet that solves your caching woes once and for all. Caching is rather a multitude of techniques for improving performance.

Some of the most important techniques are:

- [E-tags](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#conditional-get-support)
  (client side catching, don't create a new response if you don't need 
  to).
- [fragment caches]
- Using a http-accelerator in the load balancer like [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)) or [Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software))

(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) - avoid expensive render operations
 - [Model caching](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/)

Where you actually store the caches depends a bit on what type of cache it is.

Storing the cache in a shared Redis server *might* give you better performance in some cases since you will have fewer requests hitting a cold cache. However shoveling data across the interwebs from your cache server will be slower than than if it was on the individual application server.

There are always tradeoffs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

What max said is the only right answer: there is no right answer.

The point of cacheing is to limit the amount of viable requests to the server.
What I usually do:

1. Make the responses single responsibility (true REST).
2. Allow all requests that *need* fresh data through (such as profiles, users, etc)
3. Cache via varnish/squid as many requests that can have stale data as possible.
4. Use ETags on rails to allow the *application* to decide if it needs to do extra work when requests make it through the varnish/squid cache.
5. Use Redis/MemCached as much as possible on the application to reduce the cost of fetching live data.

Again there are tradeoffs. Stale data is never 100% fine. Cacheing is a bandaid that does not solve all the problems. It can only help to reduce the damage (the cost of going to the server).

Answer (score 0):

First, without knowing what type of requests your project has (i.e. shared data for multiple users vs. each user has its unique data), it's hard to give a real suggestion on a caching setup.

If the queries take multiple seconds to complete, did you try to tackle this first and try to optimize them? Maybe even switching technology from MongoDB to a regular SQL storage? Caching would only help in subsequent calls, not in the first call.

As the others said, caching may help in some cases, but having a redis up and running and powering multiple instances of your rails app adds more complexity to your setup and caching strategies only help, if you have repeated accesses to the same data.